# Is the discussionUrl for a page with Disqus comments the page the comments are embedded on?

Tags: url, schema.org, comments, disqus

When it comes to the Schema.org property [`discussionUrl`](https://schema.org/discussionUrl), Schema.org says that the `discussionUrl` should be:

> A link to the page containing the comments of the CreativeWork.

My question is, is Disqus the owner of the comments or is the page the comments are on the owner?

This last part is probably an insignificant detail but if the page is the owner of the comments, is the `discussionUrl` just the URL of the page (e.g. `http://example.com/page`) or is it the URL with the `#disqus_thread` fragment (e.g. `http://example.com/#disqus_thread`)?